# Need Help with Hair Animation in Blender!

Tags: animation, rigging, lattice

I’m trying to create an animation where the hair flicks naturally with head movement. Here’s what I did: I created a lattice with a soft body modifier, then applied this lattice as a modifier to my hair. But as soon as I apply the modifier, it loses the animation. However, I really need to apply the modifier because I want to export it in GLTF format for use on my Three.js website.
Looking for an expert to shed some light on this issue.

Here’s the link to my blender file: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/dss8vdwyl45mypxeyw2xr/softbodylattice.blend?rlkey=781ai1sz87f14g1a73rubznxp&dl=0

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)